# How to read and open a .pem file in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cryptography, pem

Hey I'm trying to open the file explorer and choose only .pem files from the device, and then get the string of the .pem content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
import { FileSystem } from 'react-native-file-access';
...

const openFile = () => {
      const type = Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? 'public.x509-certificate'
        : ['.pem', 'application/x-pem-file'];
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({ type });

      const stringifyPEM = await FileSystem.readFile(res.uri);
    }
```